# How to use backend to manage cpanel

Tags: web-applications, cpanel, backend, desktop-application

Is there a way to use desktop application (back-end) to upload files such as text and images to c panel?

So that if i will manage the front end (web app) I will just use the back-end.
I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload the files you can use filezilla as a FTP client. using filezilla you can easily connect to FTP of your host and upload , download and edit the text files.

Comment: so technically im using filezilla as my backend?